# How to retrieve the Map's field value from main class when you have function of Map<String, custom_metadata_Object__mdt>

Tags: apex, soql, map

I have a map function, I particularly want to access the function with the `npct1_Formal_Letter_Salutation_1__c` field from the custom metadata object `npct1_FC_Gender__mdt` in main class.

Below `system.debug` which calls the gender function returns `null`.

```java
System.debug('****gender function called******'+String.valueOf(getMetaDataGender().get('npct1_Formal_Letter_Salutation_1__c')));
```

Any idea how should I retrieve the `npct1_Formal_Letter_Salutation_1__c` field value, outside the function?

```java
private static Map<String, npct1_FC_Gender__mdt> getMetaDataGender(){       
 
    Map<String, npct1_FC_Gender__mdt> FCGenderMap =new Map<String,npct1_FC_Gender__mdt>
                                                   ([SELECT npct1_Gender_Pick__c, 
                                                      npct1_Formal_Letter_Salutation_1__c, 
                                                      npct1_Formal_Letter_Salutation_2__c, npct1_Addressee_Salutation__c
                                                    FROM npct1_FC_Gender__mdt
                                                    WHERE npct1_Gender_Pick__c = 'Herr']);
    system.debug('FCGenderList'+FCGenderMap.values());

    return FCGenderMap;
     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the function return type and it solved my issue.

```
private static npct1_FC_Gender__mdt getMetaDataGender(){       
    Map<String, npct1_FC_Gender__mdt> FCGenderMap =new Map<String,npct1_FC_Gender__mdt>
                                                   ([SELECT npct1_Gender_Pick__c, 
                                                      npct1_Formal_Letter_Salutation_1__c, 
                                                      npct1_Formal_Letter_Salutation_2__c, npct1_Addressee_Salutation__c
                                                    FROM npct1_FC_Gender__mdt
                                                    WHERE npct1_Gender_Pick__c = :tempGender]);
    system.debug('FCGenderList'+FCGenderMap.values());
    npct1_FC_Gender__mdt FCGenderList = FCGenderMap.values();
    return FCGenderList; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you query into a map, it will set the map key to be the Id of the record.

However, any other key you will have to set yourself.

You are not actually attempting to set ANY key after you retrieve the data, so it's likely a null key that would get you your result.

If you only want one value from this map, then perhaps you should just query into a list.

```
npct1_FC_Gender__mdt[] genders = [SELECT... etc];
return genders[0];
```

Or if you do want to get all genders, then you need to set up the map properly.

```
npct1_FC_Gender__mdt[] genders = [SELECT... etc (no WHERE - get all)];
Map<String, npct1_FC_Gender__mdt> genderMap =new Map<String,npct1_FC_Gender__mdt>();
for (npct1_FC_Gender__mdt gender : genders){
  genderMap.put(gender.npct1_Gender_Pick__c, gender);
}
return genderMap;
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
getMetaDataGender().get('herr').npct1_Formal_Letter_Salutation_1__c
```